# Having trouble with HTTP request + ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am building a project with node and am just starting to build the front end with Angular2!

My problem is I can't get it to either receive or display data, I am not entirely sure where it's crashing as I am not sure how to go about debugging angular by myself yet.

Here is the error I have been getting.

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
at new BaseException (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8080:21)
at IterableDiffers.find (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:2191:15)
at NgFor.Object.defineProperty.set [as ngForOf] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:16069:48)
at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_Roles_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:10897:14), <anonymous>:33:36)
at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8824:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8807:12)
at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8877:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8811:12)
at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8871:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8808:12)
```

Here is my Role Component(If I take *ngFor out it won't crash).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import {RoleService} from './services/roles.services';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'role-list',
  providers: [RoleService],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
      <div class ="data-table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:35%">Role</th>
                <th style="width:35%">Description</th>
                <th style="width:15%">Active</th>
                <th style="width:120px">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="#role of role_list">
                <td>{{role.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{role.ROLE_NAME}}</td>
                <td>{{role.DESCRIPTION}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    `
})
export class Roles implements OnInit{

    role_list: Array<any>;

    constructor(private _roleService: RoleService){
    };

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getRoles();
    };

    getRoles(){
        this._roleService.getRoles().subscribe(roles =>  this.role_list = roles);
    };
}
```

And My Role.services is -

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class RoleService {

    roles: Array<any>;

    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }

    getRoles(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/roles/')
            .map((responseData) =>  {
                return responseData.json()
            });
    }
}
```

I don't think this matters too much, but I will post my mock Json data here as well.

```
{
    data: [
        {
            ID: 2,
            ROLE_NAME: "Molly Holly",
            DESCRIPTION: "Holy Moly",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        },
        {
            ID: 3,
            ROLE_NAME: "I'm a Red Button",
            DESCRIPTION: "I wonder what this will do",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        },
        {
            ID: 4,
            ROLE_NAME: "Water",
            DESCRIPTION: "Getting some water in",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        },
        {
            ID: 5,
            ROLE_NAME: "Earth",
            DESCRIPTION: "Can you smell what the Rock is Cookin?",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        },
        {
            ID: 6,
            ROLE_NAME: "Fire",
            DESCRIPTION: "Something hot",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        },
        {
            ID: 7,
            ROLE_NAME: "Heart",
            DESCRIPTION: "For weenies",
            ACTIVE_FLAG: "Y"
        }
    ]
}
```

Learning angular so far has been somewhat challenging so far.  Especially because there are not too many references for the current angular2 build that are accurate for me to follow.  Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: can you show how you use ngFor?

Comment: what do you mean @pixelbits?  Do you need help with how NgFor works?

Comment: No.. You mention ngFor in the title and didn't show it your code. It may be relevant to your problem

Comment: It's in my role.component in the template.  But Gentiane answered it for me, it wasn't my for loop it was the fact I was not sending my data correctly.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply badly extracted your list from json response. You should return the data property.
The best location to this, is directly in the service :

```
export class RoleService {
    roles: Array<any>;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }

    getRoles(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/roles/')
            .map(response => response.json().data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  Just helped a colleague fix a similar issue in his code yesterday!

Comment: However you still need to subscribe to the Obervable returned by getRoles().

Comment: Wow I feel really silly now.  Thanks a ton!  Also I did that in my Role.component @ToddWCrone that's why he didn't add it to the service!  As I am new, is the better way to put it into my services?

Comment: No idea the 'best' thing.  Right now I'm just mapping it to something from the domain, like `Observable<Roles[]>` so the component does have to mess with the Response directly or JSON but it still has to subscribe to an Observable.